# ID of iOS or Android device - not user-resettable and no user permission required to pull

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am looking for a ID to identify Android and iOS device meeting the following requirements:

1. unique
2. reliably available for React Native app to pull whenever a user is making contact to the backend server
3. Not require device user permission to pull
4. NOT user-resetable. device user can not change it by her/himself.

There are a lot of online discussions and it seems to me there are more recommendation of `Android ID` for Android and `UUID` for iOS. I am new to the mobile app programming. Do `Android ID` and `UUID (iOS)` meet all requirements above, especially about the user permission and user-resettable?

Comment: Thankfully iOS doesn't provide such an id.

Comment: No, such things does not exist for iOS, at least not "legally": https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/apr/24/uber-broke-apple-ios-privacy-rules-tim-cook-travis-kalanick

Comment: Anything close in iOS? Occasional change of the ID is OK. But it can not be changed by user by going into setting.

Comment: You could just create a UUID yourself and store it in AsyncStorage. It would only then be changed if the user deleted the app and re-installed.

Comment: The standard approach on iOS is to generate a UUID and store it in the keychain. Only a device reset will remove it. If you are happy for the is to change if the user uninstall your app and later reinstalls it then `identifierForVendor` will meet your requirements

Comment: react-native-device-info module seems good for the purpose. There is API call getUniqueId() which works on iOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided way to do this is for iOS to use UIDevice:identifierForVendor(). This returns a UUID that is unique for:

1. The particular device
2. Your app

It may be reset if the app is removed and reinstalled and it will be different for different apps on the same device.

We used to use the MAC or other things, but as each of those was adopted for cross-app and cross-platform marketing purposes, Apple removed access to them to help preserve user privacy.